# A relation $R$ is defined on $\mathbb{N}$ by $aRb$ if $a|b$ $\in \mathbb{N}$. For $c, d \in \mathbb{N}$, under what condition is $c R^{-1} d$?

Tags: logic, relations

A relation $R$ is defined on $\mathbb{N}$ by $aRb$ if $a|b$ $\in \mathbb{N}$. For $c, d \in \mathbb{N}$, under what condition is $c R^{-1} d$?

My Solution

By definition of $R$, $aRb$ if $a|b \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, let $x \in \mathbb{N}$, then $b = ax$. Lets now consider $R^{-1}$, the inverse relation of $R$. For an ordered pair $\left(a, b\right) \in R^{-1}$, the ordered pair $\left(b, a\right) \in R$. Thus $\left(a,b\right)\in R^{-1}$ implies that $bRa$. Let $y\in\mathbb{N}$, then $bRa$ means that $a = by$ for $\left(a,b\right)\in R$. Since $b = ax$, it follows that $a = by = \left(ax\right)y = axy$. Dividing through by $a$, we have that $xy = 1$. Since $x, y \in \mathbb{N}, xy = 1$ if and only if $x=y=1$.

Thus, for $\left(a, b\right) = \left(a, axy\right) \in R{-1}, \left(b,a\right)\in R$ if and only if $\left(b,a\right) = \left(ax, a\right)$ and $x = y = 1$. Let $R_{1} \subset R$ defined $R_{1} = \left\{\left(a, a\right) : a \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$, then $R_{1}$ is precisely the relation that has the inverse $R^{-1}$ and $R_{1} = R^{-1}$.

Therefore, in particular, for $c, d \in \mathbb{N}, c R^{-1} d$ if and only if $c = d$.

Is my reasoning sound here; thus I am correct?
I am self-learning all of these and a beginner as such so please keep your comments as simple as possible. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to me to prove that if $aRb$ and $aR^{-1}b$ then $a=b$. But this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, that's interesting, thanks. I kind of find this question challenging. It's the first of its kind I have met, haha.  How do I go about it?

Comment: It sounds like you are making this far more complicated than it needs to be.  $cR^{-1}d$ is by definition true iff $dRc$.  It sounds like all they want you to do is word this in more normal speech which would be that $aRb$ iff $a$ divides $b$... and that $cR^{-1}d$ iff $c$ is a multiple of $d$.

Comment: The punchline is that a hypothetical pair $a,b$ that appear in the definition of $aRb$ do not need to be the same hypothetical pair of values $a,b$ used in the definition of $R^{-1}$... something even alluded to when they talked about using $c,d$ instead when they asked the question.

Comment: @JMoravitz so insightful, thank you so much. Simpler than I thought, haha. The "under what condition" part was what pushed me to the above. Thank so much.